# Send text to div in Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to send a text to a div element in web.whatsapp. I tried several ways ie using XPath, cssSelector, class name etc. but none is working for me.

[image: Web Whatsapp]

This textbox comes when we attach an image in web.whatsapp.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: Div is not a text holding element. If you further open the tree there should be an input/textfield or similar element deeper. You need to target that instead of the div.

Comment: @skandigraun no input/textfield is there. Check web.whatsapp (attach image)

Comment: Since you did not open the tree in the picture, it is not easy to guess - but indeed. This is not a textfield (not other input type), you can't type in it directly. You have to change the text content of the element. You can inject it with JavaScript, or maybe you could click on the most inner div, and use Robot to send the key events. Or you can also try performing an action, like `myDriver().actions().mouseMove(div).click().sendKeys('text').perform()`

Comment: Did you try to `sendKeys()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please step into the div and use the div with the class "selectable-text". As this is a contenteditable div you should be able to click into it and call then sendKeys() onto the element.

if this does not help please let me know then I will look in our code how we are filling such divs exactly.

Comment: Can you please give example how to use it

Comment: @AnkushKapoor please try this one:

Comment: Download the latest chromedriver and place it into the root directory. This example works out-of-the-box when beeing executed by IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drill down further until you get to a web element that takes an input.

Comment: Already did that. There is no input. You can check it on web.whatsapp (Attach image)